Unity Object reference not set to an instance of object
I am new to unity and am following a few different tutorials and i cant seem to find a solution to this issue. I have a script for my player movement called FPSController and i am using the new unity input system i think with actions. The movement was working great with sprinting and jumping all smooth. I then started learning about raycasting and interactable stuff. Then i suddenly get an error in unity with my FPS controller script on line 50.
Here is the fps controller script:
using System;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows;

public class FPSController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement Speeds")]
    [SerializeField] private float walkSpeed = 3.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float sprintMultiplier = 2.0f;

    [Header("Jump parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 5.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float gravity = 9.81f;

    [Header("Look Sensitivity")]
    [SerializeField] private float mouseSensitivity = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float upDownRange = 80.0f;

    private CharacterController characterController;
    private Camera mainCamera;
    private PlayerInputHandler inputHandler;
    private Vector3 currentMovement;
    private float verticalRotation;



private void Awake()
{
    characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    mainCamera = Camera.main;
    inputHandler = PlayerInputHandler.instance;
}

private void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    HandleMovement();
    HandleRotation();
}



private void HandleMovement()
{
    float speed = walkSpeed * (inputHandler.SprintValue > 0 ? sprintMultiplier : 1f);
    
    Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(inputHandler.MoveInput.x, 0f, inputHandler.MoveInput.y);
    Vector3 worldDirection = transform.TransformDirection(inputDirection);
    worldDirection.Normalize();

    currentMovement.x = worldDirection.x * speed;
    currentMovement.z = worldDirection.z * speed;

    HandleJumping();

    characterController.Move(currentMovement * Time.deltaTime);
}

private void HandleRotation()
{
    float mouseXRotation = inputHandler.LookInput.x * mouseSensitivity;
    transform.Rotate(0, mouseXRotation, 0);

    verticalRotation -= inputHandler.LookInput.y * mouseSensitivity;
    verticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(verticalRotation, -upDownRange, upDownRange);
    mainCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(verticalRotation, 0, 0);
}

private void HandleJumping()
{
    if(characterController.isGrounded) 
    {
        currentMovement.y = -0.5f;

        if(inputHandler.JumpTriggered)
        {
            currentMovement.y = jumpForce;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currentMovement.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
}

It worked before but now i get an error saying:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
FPSController.HandleMovement () (at Assets/Scenes/Scripts/FPSController.cs:50)
FPSController.Update () (at Assets/Scenes/Scripts/FPSController.cs:42)
Does anyone know why. I think it could be to do with me trying to add raycasting and prompt messages and i somehow messed something up. Any help much appreciated.

PlayerInputHandler.instance .. this looks like singleton pattern - despite it not being recommended - are you sure this is initialized before this class' Awake call?
